# Export data from gridview to excel without losing the gridlines

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to export to excel the grid view data.I could bind the data in excel.However when I open the grid view I am losing its grid lines which looks really bad. I have added my code below.

This code takes my grid data and exports it to excel deleting all the gridlines i tried to google couldnt find a breaktrough can someone help me with this

```
  protected void btn_export_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.Charset = "";
        string FileName = "Dashboard_FOR_PM" + DateTime.Now + ".xls";
        StringWriter strwritter = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter htmltextwrtter = new HtmlTextWriter(strwritter);
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);
        grv_dashboard.GridLines = GridLines.Both;

        grv_dashboard.HeaderStyle.Font.Bold = true;
        grv_dashboard.RenderControl(htmltextwrtter);
        Response.Write(strwritter.ToString());

        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
              Table table = new Table();
        table.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
        table.BorderWidth=new Unit(1);
        table.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
        table.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
            }
        }


        strwritter.Write(@"<html xmlns:x=""urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"">");
        strwritter.Write(@"<head>
                           <xml>
                             <x:ExcelWorkbook> 
                               <x:ExcelWorksheets>
                                   <x:ExcelWorksheet>
                                      <x:WorksheetOptions>
                                         <x:Panes></x:Panes>
                                         <x:Print><x:Gridlines /></x:Print>
                                      </x:WorksheetOptions>
                                    </x:ExcelWorksheet>
                                  </x:ExcelWorksheets>
                                </x:ExcelWorkbook>
                              </xml>
                            </head>");
        Response.End();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Have you considered maybe using a library like NPOI ?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at below function that I wrote before,please ask if something is unclear,hope it helps

```
public void ToExcel(DataTable dt, string reportName)
    {
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            string filename = string.Format("{0}.xls", reportName);
            System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            HtmlForm hf = new HtmlForm();

            DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();

            dg.DataSource = dt;
            dg.HeaderStyle.BackColor = Color.Tomato;//change to your own colors
            dg.HeaderStyle.ForeColor = Color.White;//change to your own colors
            dg.BackColor = Color.LightGoldenrodYellow;//change to your own colors
            dg.AlternatingItemStyle.BackColor = Color.PaleGoldenrod;//change to your own colors
            dg.Font.Name = "Tahoma";
            dg.Font.Size = 10;
            dg.GridLines = GridLines.Both;
            dg.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            dg.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
            dg.BorderWidth = new Unit(1);
            dg.DataBind();

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename);

            HttpContext.Current.Response.Charset = "";
            EnableViewState = false;
            Controls.Add(hf);
            hf.Controls.Add(dg);
            hf.RenderControl(htw);
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sw.ToString());
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: what do i mention in string reportname

Comment: just a name for excel file,something like "Dashboard_FOR_PM" + DateTime.Now

Comment: i tried ur code but my problem is i have displayed colors in my grid cells and want to show as it is so i cannot change my datagrid color also do i have to add something to my code which will show me gridlines

Comment: can u have a look at my question i have edited it and shown the desired output so i dont think ur code relly works well for me. i cannot have such gridview data in datatable

Comment: @anita actually you can generate datatable as you need